# Does 'lure' have a negative connotation

Tags: word-usage

I'm looking for a name for my website which has the purpose of attracting people. I stumble across the word 'lure'. But I was wondering if the verb 'lure' has a negative connotation. Can any native speaker tell me this? And can you say 'lure at you'?

Many thanks!

Comment: This question is fine here, but seeing that you're new to the Stack Exchange, and you've mentioned "native speaker," I thought you might appreciate a pointer to our site for [ell.se].

Comment: Depends on whether you're a fisherman or a fish.

Comment: It has a slightly negative connotation in that you're trying to attract someone's attention by subterfuge. Also, you lure someone, (you don't lure _at_ someone).

Answer (score 7):

It absolutely does have a negative connotation—one of bait and switch.

Phrases like "*After luring her into his house, ...*" and "*The victims were lured into following...*" are common in the news.

If you want to attract people using real content, then this is a very bad name for the project. On the other hand, if cheap tricks and memes are your means to clicking on banners and ads, then it's perfect.

Comment: I agree – a better word would probably be _attract_.

Comment: I would quibble that the use of the word "absolutely" shouldn't be taken to indicate the strength or degree of negativity. Lure can have a sense that is anywhere from neutral to extremely negative.

Answer (score 2):

Lure - defined as to tempt - I s often associated with negative connotations. Fishing lures are fake baits. Offenders are often referenced as having lured their prey to a dark or secluded location for example.

Depending on the nature of the website, allure could be a good alternative:
the quality of being powerfully and mysteriously attractive or fascinating.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there is an inference of deception in 'lure', although perhaps not always. In fishing for example, a lure is a mock-fish with embedded hook so that you do not need genuine bait

Answer (score 0):

If it is akin to "lock" (viz Ger "locken", to bait, lure), which makes sense insofar *k* after long vowels lenited, which could become anything from /h/ to /x/ or even *r*, then yeah, it's hella negative and semantically equivalent to "trap"; cp "in die Falle locken" (to lure into the trap; possibly *to lock into the trap*); Further cp *Loch* "hole", *einlochen* "imprisson".

These may not be directly related, I didn't check (*k*>*r* would be rare as far as I know), but the connotation is there, and .. convergence trumps root genetics.